# Blacklight CFL Bulb Effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, photorealism

I have been searching everywhere, and I can't find an answer so I'm coming here!

I'm trying to create a CFL Blacklight bulb. I've attached a couple images below of what I've tried to make. I'd love to have an effect like this:

[image: blacklight bulb from https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Frugbyexpress.co%2Fuv-black-light-bulbs%2F&psig=AOvVaw1hpDIYpbkXsUt0TH1zm54N&ust=1581378193662000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJj2mf7SxecCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAZ]

Does anyone know how to recreate this? It seems like the color is affected by time as the bulb heats up, eventually being all white-ish. That would be fine, too, but I can't even seem to get the lighting effect of the pink glow around it and whatnot. I can post pictures of my node setup if you need it, though I think I made it necessarily complicated.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
This is what I have now:
[image: Blender render of my light bulb]

I want to adjust the colors, but that isn't the issue now... The way I made this is a glass spiral that acts as the bulb. Inside of that bulb (that has a glass-like shader) is a purple material that I made that mimics the phosphor coating blacklight light bulbs have to filter light. Then, a separate mesh spiral is inside of that, and it has the emission stuff on it.

As Duarte suggested, I used the node setup he had for my emission, but used a transparent node instead of glossy. Why isn't the emission light from inside my glass causing the glass to be glossy? If I put a point light in the scene, it looks glossy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is trivial to achieve using normal based effects like Fresnel.

You can use it both for the color gradient, and the shader transition from glossy to emission shader.

A layer Weight Node should give you both the *Facing* socket for the colors and a *Fresnel* socket for the shaders.

Drive it through a *Color Ramp node* to control the color progression gradient, and link the *Fresnel* socket to a Shader Mix node for shader mixing, between say an *Emission node* and *Glossy*, or Emission and transparent if you will.

[image]

Comment: Yeah - use this one - it's so much better than mine :)

Comment: Ah this is awesome! I can't believe it was this easy... This is my first more photo-realistic render, so I'm learning a lot. One question, though. I can't seem to get my bulb to look as glossy. I attached photos in the original post and an explanation of how I'm making things.

Comment: Glass shader doesn't usually show as many reflections as a glossy shader. Also mixing with other shaders tends to attenuate the effects, particularly emission shaders tend to wash out all other effects.

Comment: I marked yours as correct, you've been a huge help, thank you! One more question: If you look at the reference picture, the inside of the spiral is not as lit as the outside. Any idea how to make an effect like that?

Comment: You'd probably have to use some sort of different mask to mix two shaders or colors. Maybe a spherical or cylindrical gradient of some sort

Comment: What do you mean by a different mask? Like a texture map with gray scale values do indicate where I was it dimmer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could get you close. There's lots of tweaking you could still do and this isn't physically accurate in any way, shape or form.

[image]

[image]

Play around with the Mix Shader inputs and the IOR settings of the Fresnel nodes.